# Request Method Mudando de GET para OPTIONS sozinho

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, get

Estou com o seguinte código:

```
$(function() {
    $('#method').change(function() {
        var method = $(this).val();
        if (method == 'GET' || method == 'DELETE')
            $('#json-group').hide();
        else
            $('#json-group').show();
    });

    $('#send-button').click(function() {
        var url = $('#url').val()
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.href = url;
        var method = $('#method').val();
        if (method == 'GET')
            var data = '';
        else
            var data = $.trim($('#json').val());
        var md5 = data ? CryptoJS.MD5(data).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64) : '';
        var date = (new Date()).toUTCString();

        var parts = [method, md5, date, a.pathname].join('\n');
        var hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(parts, $('#api_secret').val());
        var sig = hmac.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
        var auth = 'Zopim-Reseller-API ' + $('#api_token').val() + ':' + sig;
        var headers = {'API-Date': date, Authorization: auth};
         $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: method,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function() { alert('hello!'); },
      error: function() { alert('boo!'); },
      beforeSend: setHeader
         });

         function setHeader(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('API-Date', date);
  }
    });
});
```

Esse código deveria mandar uma requisição GET, só que no Chrome ele me informa os seguintes dados:

> Remote Address:67.23.229.9:443 
>  Request
>   URL:https://reseller.zopim.com/api/info 
>  **Request Method:OPTIONS**
>   
>  Status Code:200 OK 
>   Request Headersview source 
>   Accept:*/* 
>  Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch 
>   Accept-Language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4 
>   Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization, api-date 
>   Access-Control-Request-Method:GET 
>  Connection:keep-alive 
>   Host:reseller.zopim.com 
>  Origin:http://zopim.net.br

E por consequência da esse erro:

> *XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://reseller.zopim.com/api/info. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.*

Comment: Lendo a documentação para `/info` aqui: __https://sites.google.com/a/zopim.com/reseller/api/info__ vejo que o que eles querem é email e password. Já tentou isso ou o token como chave do header?

Comment: Essas 2 linhas: `var auth = 'Zopim-Reseller-API ' + $('#api_token').val() + ':' + sig;
 var headers = {'API-Date': date, Authorization: auth};` São as que formam o HEADER para ele fazer uma especie de login para pegar as informações do /info só que envez de ficar como GET está me retornando como se eu tivesse mandado OPTIONS

Comment: E já tentou usar os parametros que eles referem no CURL? `xhr.setRequestHeader('email', email); xhr.setRequestHeader('password', password);` ?

Comment: Não, mas eles se referem a autentificação da variavel auth e do parametro 'API-Date'

Comment: Nessa página `/info` não encontro nada sobre autentificação com `API-Date`. Onde está essa informação?

Answer (score 2):

O problema é [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

O protocolo HTTP considera, como **requisições simples**, os seguintes métodos:

- GET
- POST
- HEAD

Os demais, como `OPTIONS`, são [*Preflighted* Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). `OPTIONS` em específico serve para zelar pela segurança da requisição. Os dados trafegados vão até o servidor para ele determinar se são informações seguras ou não – caso sejam, o objeto é "descompactado" e lido de uma determinada maneira prevista pelo próprio [servidor].

O seu `dataType`, neste caso, é `json`, o seu método é `GET`, e você está usando um `header` personalizado, portanto, a sua requisição **é** "preflighted" – o que significa que a menos que seja especificado no servidor, o método será `OPTIONS`.

Answer (score 0):

O que ocorre é o seguinte, para métodos de requisição HTTP que podem causar efeitos colaterais nos dados do servidor (em particular, para métodos HTTP que não sejam GET, ou para utilização de GET com certos MIME types), a especificação determina que navegadores "pré-enviem" a requisição, solicitando os métodos suportados pelo servidor com um método de requisição HTTP OPTIONS, e depois, após "aprovação" do servidor, envie a requisição verdadeira com o método de requisição HTTP efetivo.

Por padrão os navegadores não enviam o HTTP Header Authorization nas requisições HTTP OPTIONS, portanto o seu servidor/API deve estar exigindo Authorization para todos o Métodos HTTP e por isso dá erro na primeira requisição HTTP OPTIONS e barra a requisição HTTP GET.

Para corrigir o problema você deve configurar seu servidor/API para permitir requisições HTTP OPTIONS sem o Header Authorization.

Informações retiradas de:
 - [Controle de Acesso HTTP (CORS) - HTTP | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS)
 - [cors - Authorization header not sent with http request angular 6 with OPTIONS method - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51467977/8133067)